# Write Python object attributes to txt file

Tags: python, oop

I would like to create a "metadata" file for several Python objects I have built and was wondering if there was an elegant way to write a subset of these attributes to a .txt file. Ideally, the .txt file would have the following formatting:

```
object.Name = thisistheobjectname object.Value = thisistheobjectvalue etc...
```

Comment: Why not just use pickle to serialize the object to a file?

Comment: Industry standard these days is JSON of you want something human readable.

Comment: Great, thanks.  Can I pickle only a subset of object attributes?

Comment: How do you intend on determining and defining the subset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your goal is to reuse this object later on, then don't reinvent the wheel and use `pickle`.
But if your goal is to just get objects variables in a nice looking txt file then you can leverage `__dict__` of the object

You can ether store it in `JSON` or convert it to what ever works for you:

For example:

```
import json

class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self, name, value):
    self.name = name
    self.value = value

myfoo = Foo('abc', 'xyz')
with open('foo.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write(' '.join(["myfoo.%s = %s" % (k,v) for k,v in myfoo.__dict__.iteritems()]))
```

Will result in something like:

```
myfoo.name = abc myfoo.value = xyz
```

Comment: How can I make the object name variable as well? 
I tried:

f.write('\n'.join(["{}.{} = '{}'".format(objname.name, (k for k in objname.__dict__.keys()),(v for v in objname.__dict__.values()))]))

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something simple, you can use this for your example above.

```
import sys
class Foo(object):
    bar = 'hello'
    baz = 'world'

f = Foo()
print "\n".join(("`%s.Name=%s %s.Value=%s`" % (f.__class__.__name__, name, f.__class__.__name__, getattr(f, name)) for name in dir(f) if not name.startswith("__")))
```

will give

```
`Foo.Name=bar Foo.Value=hello`
`Foo.Name=baz Foo.Value=world`
```

For more complex serialization you are better off using pickle

Answer (score 0):

Use Pickle library for object serialization.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html